# How to remap a kernel

Tags: c, assembly, kernel, virtual-memory, osdev

This is a theoretical question as I can't seem to find any reference on how to do this.

I am writing a small kernel and I already have virtual memory working.

I have defined my memory map (taking inspiration from https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/x86/x86_64/mm.txt) and now I want to set up the layout.

I have the following function that maps physical pages to virtual addresses:

```
void mapMemory(void* virtualMemory, void* physicalMemory)
```

Given an arbitrary memory region (*somebuffer* in the example) defined by the following struct:

```
struct region {
    void * base;
    uint64_t size;
};
```

I can remap physical pages to arbitrary addresses (*OFFSET* in the example)

```
uint64_t address = somebuffer.base;
uint64_t size    = somebuffer.size;

uint64_t index = 0;
for (uint64_t i = address; i < (address+size); i += 0x1000) {
    mapMemory((void*)OFFSET+index, (void*)i);
    index += 0x1000;
}
```

and then manually fix the pointers like this:

```
somebuffer.base = (void*)OFFSET;
```

This way I can still access *somebuffer*.

What I want is to remap the entire runtime (kernel segments, stack, EFI runtime services, etc) but I'm lacking that part of *osdev* theory. So, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Some ideas I had so far on how to solve this:

- For the stack: just add the offset to `rbp` and `rsp` using embedded assembly.
- For the kernel: modifying the entries in the *GDT*.
- For the kernel: altering the segment registers and doing a *far jump*.

Thank you in advance!

P.S. You can check a working solution in the answer below.

Comment: The general idea is that you never change virtual addresses, only physical addresses.  This way, you won't have to change your pointers as all memory accesses go through page translation.  Remapping the kernel into some other memory is then just a matter of copying to the other memory and changing the page tables (carefully, while interrupts are off).

Comment: The way to do this is to tell your linker which addresses the kernel will have. Then you write assembly code which maps the kernel's physical addresses to the addresses you told the linker.  And you run that code first. Then by the time the main part of the kernel runs, everything is already in the right place!

Comment: So what if your kernel is already at the “wrong” virtual address?  Well, that's a bad situation and you should avoid it completely.  The solution to avoiding this is to map the kernel to the right virtual address directly.  It may possibly required to have the code that initially sets up the page tables to be part of a boot loader or other isolated part of the code so it doesn't change its address when you load/map the rest of the kernel.

Comment: So (correct me if I'm wrong) the correct approach would be to create a second stage bootloader that sets up paging and maps the kernel, then modify the linker of the current elf so that it already starts in the desired (virtual address).

Comment: Instead of a second-stage bootloader, think of it as some early init work in your kernel's entry point, which runs before jumping to any compiled C.  It can be part of the same kernel image that contains your compiled code, it's just written in a position-independent way so it works in the environment that exists on entry to it.

Comment: @Tretorn This is correct.  However, you usually do this int he way Peter Cordes recommends.

Comment: Please don't edit an answer into the question.  If you want to share what worked for you, post that *as an answer*, with the "answer my own question" button.  So do that and roll back your edit, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stack is relative so there is no requirement to add stack offsets or anything. The requirement on the stack depends on the use of the frame pointer or not. With gcc, you can specify not to use a frame pointer with `-fomit-frame-pointer`. The difference with this option is that the local variables will be accessed by using a relative positive offset from RSP. If you do use a frame pointer, then local variables will be accessed using a relative negative offset from RBP.

The problem with changing the stacks position in your kernel revolves around the stack frame's allocation. If your compiler allocates a certain amount of stack for your main function and you change the stacks position in the main function with a too small stack frame, then this will break your kernel down the road. The problem is that the code itself will access a region of the stack that is not supposed to be accessed outside of the stack frame (maybe it is not paged or it contains some other important code/data). Also, when another function is called, the new function might overwrite some data of the main function that the main function has already initialized and used.

On the same line of thought, if you change the position of the stack in the main function, then you need to make sure that anything previously initialized is not used further in the function. This is because your stack is now somewhere else so you cannot consider that the data found in your stack frame is the same (unless you rebuild it manually).

Normally, this is the essence of paging. You can change your stack's considered position in virtual memory and have that region point to any position within physical memory (including its previous position).

The kernel's position also doesn't need to be changed. What is normally done is that the kernel's code is adjusted to expect running in the top half of the virtual address space. The kernel is loaded somewhere low in physical memory and the page tables adjusted so that the addresses contained in the kernel's code point to that position.

There are other things that you mention which don't seem to make sense. If you modify the GDT, it doesn't have an impact on paging. Actually, the GDT should probably be modified on exit from UEFI but it should only be to "take control" of the GDT (knowing its entry numbers, etc). The GDT should still represent a flat memory model spanning the whole of the address space. Anyway, as to what I know, the limit in the GDT is ignored in long mode. You should really just use paging.

If you want to modify the GDT on UEFI exit, then you are right that you have to modify the segment registers but for CS you need a far return. Long mode doesn't support far jumps. I don't remember the details but you need the new CS value and the return address on the stack before the far return instruction.

You also cannot remap UEFI runtime services as these are gone once you exit the UEFI environment. UEFI works similarly to a small kernel. Once you modify the execution environment, the small kernel breaks (you change IA32_LSTAR, you change syscall numbers, you change the GDT, etc). In any case, if you wanted to use these services in a custom kernel, you'd need to know what are the syscall numbers in the UEFI standard and manually call them with inline assembly which isn't very effective. You are better forgetting about those once you exit the UEFI environment and concentrate on building your own execution environment from scratch along with your own syscalls and drivers.

Comment: Just adding a few thoughts: The GDT idea was, indeed, a bad one. UEFI Runtime Services are not gone after calling ExitBootServices (but, as you said, they depend on a specific execution environment that can and will probably change). My solution was to modify the linker script to create two groups of sections: Before paging (VMA=LMA lower addresses) with the code that sets up the page tables and after paging (VMA=Higher half, LMA=right after the first group) (the kernel itself). GDT is just set flat right after the UEFI bootloader exits and pretty much works okay.

Answer (score 1):

How i solved it:

First of all: Thank you all for the help! My solution is based on your advice and the credit is yours. I'm posting this for sake of helping others if somehow someone ends up like me.

To solve this problem first I had to create a separate folder in my project and copy all the files involved in the boot process before paging is enabled. Slight edits were made at this point.

Then I edited my linker script to something like this:

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf64-x86-64)
ENTRY(_start)

SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x8000;
    _BootStart = .;
    .boot : ALIGN(0x1000)
    {
        lib/entry/*.o (.text);
        lib/entry/*.o (.data);
        lib/entry/*.o (.rodata);
        lib/entry/*.o (.bss);
    }
    . = 0x20008000;
    _BootEnd = .;

    . = 0xffffffff80000000;
    .kernel : AT(_BootEnd)
    {
        *(.text)
        *(.data)
        *(.rodata)
        *(COMMON)
        *(.bss)
    }
    . = 0xffffffff9fffffff;

    /DISCARD/ : {
        *(.discard)
        *(.eh_frame)
        *(.eh_frame_hdr)
    }
}
```

I know, pretty bad linker script... But it does the job.

With this layout, my program will be loaded in two parts: boot and kernel. The first one starts at the address `0x8000` and will span the next 512 megabytes. It will run before paging so `VMA=LMA` in this case.

The second one (the kernel) will be loaded at the physical address right after the boot section ends, but memory accesses will point to the virtual address `0xffffffff80000000` and above.

With this linking scheme, I just have to set up paging on the first part of the code so the MMU maps the physical address of the kernel to that higher address.

A few problems and their solutions:

After paging is enabled, the kernel crashes: Remember to identity map the first part of the kernel or it will crash after setting `cr3`
My global variables still map to the higher address even when defined on a boot file: Global variables usually belong in the `COMMON` section. Declare them as `extern` to avoid this problem.

Comment: Posting your solution is 1A role model behavior. I wish more people asking questions here would post their ultimate solution as a self-answer. 